# Are security questions also UX questions?

Tags: discussion

I've been thinking. If someone asks about security (not implementation), is that considered a UX question? Because good security could potentially be good UX.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Security falls under UX if you're asking about the UX of security rather than implementation.  There is even a [security tag](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security), which should indicate that security questions are allowed.

Take a look at some of those to get an idea of what is considered UX.

Comment: Yes. If the focus of the question is the *User Experience* then this is the right site. But if the focus of the question is the security decisions then http://security.stackexchange.com is a better home. In almost all situations there is one, and only one suitable Stackexchange home for a question, so pick the site that is the best fit.

Comment: Cool, thanks for that :)

Comment: for example, there is a healthy set of questions here about the usability of passwords (also has it's own tag) - a very security oriented topic, though one with an important UX slant as they involve people too, good answers to these questions do often mention security